# Start SimpleHTTPServer on boot

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to get python's SimpleHTTPServer to start on boot using /etc/init/pyweb.conf and to specify the path which the script will be executed in and server files from, however I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Here's what I have ended up with, but it's not firing off:

```
# Start SimpleHTTPServer
#
description "SimpleHTTPServer"
start on startup
task
exec python -m SimpleHTTPServer 
--path=/var/pyweb/
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
cd
```

into that folder and run

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

from there?

Answer (score 1):

Add `chdir /var/pyweb` before your `exec`-line.

Described here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#chdir

**Edit:** To be clear, SimpleHTTPServer doesn't take any --path or other options like that. You can give it a port number, that's about it.

Also, you don't want to use it as something permanent (i.e. on boot, used a lot); use a *real* httpd for that.

Thirdly; this is more of [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) question.

Comment: Thanks very much for suggestions adding the chdir solved it.

This is to be used for a touchscreen web config, the web server will probably serve one page during initial setup and potentially never serve another page unless the config is changed which is unlikely.

many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change to a directory containing web files, for example:

`cd /var/www/test`

Run this command:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

If the default port (8000) isn't available, you can try a different one by adding it to the command:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234`

Once this is working, you can run the command below to make the server persistent:

`nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234 &`

Comment: Your solution duplicates an earlier one (please do read all answers before posting a new one), and as the OP is using `upstart` there's no use for `nohup` (although for anyone doing the same without `upstart` it would be useful).